# Ошибка HTTP 422 axios

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, post, axios

Отправляю данные пользователя при регистрации на сервер, используя axios:

```
    let userInfo = {
        name: signUpName,
        email: signUpEmail,
        registration_date: regDate,
        password: signUpPassword
    };

    let jsonUser = JSON.stringify(userInfo);

    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/create/', jsonUser)
    .then(function (response) {            
        console.log(response);
        window.location.href = '/login';
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Ошибка HTTP при создании пользователя: " + error);
    });
```

Но каждый раз получаю ошибку 422. Испробовал разные варианты решения проблемы, но ничего не помогает. Также пробовал делать это без axios:

```
    let response_create_user = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/create/',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(userInfo)
    });
```

Аналогично ошибка 422.

upd:
Бэк:

```
    class User(BaseModel):
        name: str
        email: EmailStr
        registration_date: datetime
        password: str
    
        #Валидатор на длину пароля (8+)
        @validator('password')
        def password_validator(cls, password):
            if len(password) < 8:
                raise ValueError('password length less than 8')
            return password

    User = Table('my_user', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer(), nullable=False, unique=True, 
        primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
        Column('name', String(127), nullable=False, primary_key=True, 
        unique=True),
        Column('email', String(255), nullable=False, unique=True),
        Column('registration_date', DateTime(), nullable=False),
        Column('hashpass', String(255), nullable=False),
    )

    def create_user (user: user_schema):
        hashpass_obj = hashlib.sha256(bytes(user.password, 'utf-8'))
        ins = insert(User).values(
            name = user.name,
            email = user.email,
            registration_date = user.registration_date,
            hashpass = hashpass_obj.hexdigest()
        )
        conn = engine.connect()
        r = conn.execute(ins)
        return r
```

Comment: серверную часть неплохо бы приложить

Comment: Код состояния ответа HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity указывает, что сервер понимает тип содержимого в теле запроса и синтаксис запроса является правильным, но серверу не удалось обработать инструкции содержимого.

Comment: 99%, что 422 ошибка - это невалидные данные, которые Вы отправили. Сервер по-хорошему должен ответить, что именно не так в данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify возможно не нужен (никогда не использовал вместе с аксиcом) или структура не соответствует той что хочет бэк.